# Many git processes running and exhausting available RAM

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, process

In my ubuntu machine, number of git processes are running all of sudden. That's consuming most of memory **causing my machine to stop working**.

```
$ ps aux | grep git
1417676764 13890 8.0  0.2 32428 11584 ?        R    18:04   0:08 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 14143 8.5  0.3 32560 11696 ?        R    18:04   0:09 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 14380 8.1  0.2 32300 11476 ?        R    18:04   0:08 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 14518 8.9  0.3 32592 11768 ?        R    18:04   0:08 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 14851 8.3  0.2 32204 11372 ?        R    18:04   0:08 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 14994 8.3  0.2 32104 11196 ?        R    18:04   0:07 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 15127 9.0  0.2 32204 11368 ?        R    18:04   0:08 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 15261 8.2  0.2 31424 10544 ?        R    18:04   0:07 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 15392 8.0  0.2 31148 10260 ?        R    18:05   0:06 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 15524 8.0  0.2 31044 10136 ?        R    18:05   0:06 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 15662 8.3  0.2 31044 10140 ?        R    18:05   0:06 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 15794 8.7  0.2 31044 10136 ?        R    18:05   0:06 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 15938 8.7  0.2 30948  9992 ?        R    18:05   0:06 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 16073 8.3  0.2 30396  9444 ?        R    18:05   0:05 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 16197 8.9  0.2 30852  9868 ?        R    18:05   0:05 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 16334 9.2  0.2 30948  9992 ?        R    18:05   0:05 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 16473 8.2  0.2 29528  8708 ?        R    18:05   0:04 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 16611 8.3  0.2 29424  8484 ?        R    18:05   0:04 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 16783 7.7  0.1 28556  7612 ?        R    18:05   0:04 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 16891 8.0  0.2 28780  7884 ?        R    18:05   0:04 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 17019 8.0  0.1 28556  7608 ?        R    18:05   0:04 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 17145 9.5  0.2 29044  8016 ?        R    18:05   0:04 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 17289 8.4  0.1 28392  7332 ?        R    18:05   0:03 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 17427 7.8  0.1 28064  7132 ?        R    18:05   0:03 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 17582 7.4  0.1 27460  6488 ?        R    18:05   0:02 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 17756 7.9  0.1 27112  6156 ?        R    18:05   0:02 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 17854 9.2  0.2 28848  7912 ?        R    18:05   0:03 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 18001 9.6  0.1 27460  6488 ?        R    18:05   0:03 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 18130 6.6  0.1 26260  5392 ?        R    18:05   0:01 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 18256 7.7  0.1 26364  5636 ?        R    18:05   0:02 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 18390 6.3  0.1 25492  4720 ?        R    18:06   0:01 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 19260 43.5  0.2 29292 8488 ?        R    18:06   0:04 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 19386 45.5  0.2 28652 7796 ?        R    18:06   0:03 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 19514 52.8  0.2 30592 9644 ?        R    18:06   0:03 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 19685 46.5  0.1 24964 4212 ?        R    18:06   0:00 git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
1417676764 19774 0.0  0.0 13612   876 pts/1    S+   18:06   0:00 grep --color=auto git
```

The processes keep increasing with time.

I killed the processes with following command as a temporary solution,

`$ pkill git`

But couldn't figure out the cause of git running as **processes**.

`$ pstree -apl` command gives me following output.

```
  |-tmux,3001 -2
  |   |-bash,3002
  |   |   `-pstree,10343 -apl
  |   |-sh,3003 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,3005 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,3528 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,3550 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,3557 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,3559 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,3560 -l
  |   |-sh,3333 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,3335 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,3527 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,3549 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,3555 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,3556 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,3558 -l
  |   |-sh,3573 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,3575 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,3728 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,3739 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,3742 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,3743 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,3744 -l
  |   |-sh,3800 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,3801 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,3909 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,3920 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,3923 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,3924 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,3925 -l
  |   |-sh,3926 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,3927 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4035 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4046 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4049 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4050 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4051 -l
  |   |-sh,4052 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4053 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4161 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4172 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4175 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4176 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4177 -l
  |   |-sh,4178 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4179 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4287 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4298 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4301 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4302 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4303 -l
  |   |-sh,4305 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4306 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4414 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4425 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4428 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4429 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4430 -l
  |   |-sh,4432 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4433 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4541 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4552 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4555 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4556 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4557 -l
  |   |-sh,4558 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4559 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4667 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4678 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4681 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4682 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4683 -l
  |   |-sh,4684 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4685 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4793 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4804 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4807 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4808 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4809 -l
  |   |-sh,4810 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4811 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,4919 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,4930 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,4933 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,4934 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,4935 -l
  |   |-sh,4936 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,4937 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,5045 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,5056 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,5059 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,5060 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,5061 -l
  |   |-sh,5062 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,5063 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,5171 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,5182 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,5185 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,5186 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,5187 -l
  |   |-sh,5188 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,5189 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,5297 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,5308 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,5311 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,5312 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,5313 -l
  |   |-sh,5358 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,5359 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,5467 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,5478 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,5481 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,5482 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,5483 -l
  |   |-sh,5489 -c ~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |   `-bash,5490 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |       `-bash,5598 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |           `-bash,5609 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |               `-bash,5612 /home/prayag/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left
  |   |                   |-git,5613 ls-files --others --exclude-standard
  |   |                   `-wc,5614 -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like these, [`pstree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/pstree.1.html) can help you identify where the process was started:

```
pstree -apl
```

will list all running processes with their parent processes (=process which started it). That should help you figure out what launched all these git processes.

If you have figured this out, you can see how you can stop them from being started...

Comment: Loved the command `$ pstree -apl`. The issue was with `tmux` which I had set as default terminal(`[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux -2`) in `.bashrc`. Removing it from `.bashrc` fixes the problem. Will look further. Thanks for `pstree`.